# How to SFTP into a KVM VM on remote RHEL 7.2 server?

Tags: virtual-machine, sftp

We have a RHEL 7.2 server which runs a virtual RHEL 7.2 machine on KVM.
The only way to connect to this VM is to SSH to the server and then SSH again to the VM, using a user on server.

How can I connect to the VM via SFTP so that I can manipulate the files through Krusader and similar clients?

Comment: That depends on your VM system, its network configuration, the host's network configuration, and firewall rules.  Does that VM have Internet access?

Comment: It does have internet access. Regarding the FW and net config, assume defaults. Or just shoot the 1st thing that comes into your mind :)

Comment: You're not helping yourself.  If you want help in troubleshooting a complex issue, you need to provide as much detail as you can.  Unless you post your IP or password, no hacker is going to benefit from your post.

Comment: Right, I didn't put much information. Fixed. But it seems that the general approach with port tunneling is the way to go.

Answer (score 1):

Typically virtual box and VMware both configure the network connection to the vm via the host to be NAT based, on an isolated subnet from the the test of the LAN. This has the benefits and drawbacks of the NAT implementation on most peoples home routers. 
You aren't 'visible' to the network/internet unless you initiate the traffic or configure port forwarding. In the case of a server application, you need to specifically have the host forward packets on the port, 21/22 in this case to your IP address of the guest system.

I nearly always configure my vms to operate in bridged mode instead of NAT in part to avoid this. I can't tell you how to do that exactly because you didn't tell us what vm software you are running. It is very easy to do though.

In bridged mode the guest will get an IP address from the lan DHCP server, and will be in the same lan as all the other clients, making what you are trying to do trivial.